# PowerShell TrimStart not always working

Tags: powershell, trim

I'm trying to trim the beginning of a string, but it doesn't always work correctly with `TrimStart()`. In the first example below it works fine, but in the second it doesn't.

**Correct result:**

```
$Array = 'C:\Users\boblee\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Beez\ISO\ISO\Environnement',
'C:\Users\boblee\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Beez\ISO',
'C:\Users\boblee\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Beez\ISO\Achat'
$Array | % {$_.TrimStart('C:\Users\boblee\AppData\Local\Temp\2')}
```

**Wrong result:**

```
$Array = 'S:\Test\Bob\Out_Test\Beez\ISO\ISO\Environnement',
'S:\Test\Bob\Out_Test\Beez\ISO',
'S:\Test\Bob\Out_Test\Beez\ISO\Achat'
$Array | % {$_.TrimStart('S:\Test\Bob\Out_Test\')}
```

Can anyone help me out what the best way would be to trim of the beginning of the strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use replace instead, like so:

```
$string = 'S:\Test\Bob\Out_Test\Beez\ISO\ISO\Environnement'
$string.Replace('S:\Test\Bob\Out_Test\','')
```

The reason why trimstart don't work is because it doesn work as you would expect. The input you give it, is not a string, but an array of characters.

You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Awesome! This does the trick indeed. Thank you very much ojk :)